# Virtual function performance when called by derived classes?

Tags: c++, performance, function, virtual, derived-class

Is there a performance penalty when a virtual method is called from a class that's known to be the derived class at compile time?  Below I explicitly call `force_speak` with a derived class.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
  virtual void speak()
  {
    std::cout << "base" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
  void speak()
  {
    std::cout << "derived 1" << std::endl;
  }
};

template<class B>
void force_speak(std::array<std::unique_ptr<B>, 3>& arr)
{
  for (auto& b: arr)
  {
    b->speak();
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::array<std::unique_ptr<Derived1>, 3> arr = 
    {
      std::unique_ptr<Derived1>(new Derived1),
      std::unique_ptr<Derived1>(new Derived1),
      std::unique_ptr<Derived1>(new Derived1)
    };
  force_speak(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should ask one question at a time.

Comment: What is a performance penalty, something you think it is or something you measured (or better recognized as one) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a performance penalty when a virtual method is called from a class that's known to be the derived class at compile time? See code below.

It depends. Most compilers will "de-virtualize" code like this:

```
Derived1 d;
d.speak();
```

The dynamic type of the object is known at the call site, so the compiler can avoid going through the vtable to make the call and can just call `Derived1::speak()` directly.

In your example the compiler needs to be smarter because in `force_speak` you only have  `Derived1*` pointers (stored inside the `unique_ptr` objects) and in that context it's not clear whether the dynamic type of the pointed-to objects is `Derived1` or some more-derived type.  The compiler either needs to inline the call to `force_speak` into `main` (where the dynamic type is known) or use some additional knowledge about the type to allow devirtualization to happen. (As one example of additional knowledge, whole program optimization can determine that there *are* no other derived types declared anywhere in the program, so a `Derived1*` *must* point to a `Derived1`.)

Using the C++11 `final` keyword can help compilers to devirtualize some cases, e.g. if `Derived1` is marked `final` then the compiler knows that a `Derived1*` can only point to a `Derived1` and not some other type derived from it that might override `speak()`

Comment: Looking at the assembly, looks like neither GCC nor Clang fully devirtualizes the call in OP's code. (GCC does something clever, it inlines `Derived1::speak()` and does a comparison on the vtable pointer, jumping to a virtual call only if the comparison is unequal.) `final` on either class or the function makes it devirtualized.

Comment: @T.C. Is there any need for the template parameter `B` in `force_speak`, i.e. can I declare `force_speak` as `void force_speak(std::array<std::unique_ptr<Base>, 3>& arr)` and still get devirtualization using final?  Thanks.

Comment: @anon, you can't do that, `array<unique_ptr<Derived1>, N>` is not convertible to `array<unique_ptr<Base>, N>`

Answer (score 2):

1. It's compiler dependent. Compiler must statically know that `Derived1:speak()` is the only option. That includes knowing that there is no some `Derived2::speak()` definition, where `class Derived2: public Derived1`. But compiler might not implement such an optimization at all.
2. Function template parameters can be deduced automatically by a compiler. This is part of C++ standard. Compiler knows the type of parameter at a call site so user does not have to provide it. Note, that user can provide the type, and thay can for example provide type compatible but different that the type of an actual parameter.

Comment: Thanks for answering the 2nd question (now removed).

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, the answer is *maybe*.

If the compiler decides to inline `force_speak()` it could theoretically deduce that all of the pointers in the array are `Derived1` instances and so call the method statically.  (This optimization is not required by the standard, so whether the method is called statically or virtually depends on your particular compiler and possibly what options you use during compilation.)

If the compiler does not inline the call then it *must* emit instructions to call the method virtually, because you could further derive the class `Derived1` and override the method yet again, store instances of that class in `std::unique_ptr<Derived1>`, and pass an array of those into the function.